# Issue with Java while retreiving postgresql timestamptz data

Tags: java, postgresql, timezone, timestamp, ibatis

Here Is the Situation. We have a AWS server where we are going to deploy our application for our customers(who are basically from different parts of the world). We are using postgresql database,Java7, ibatis for our application.
For each customer we are going to have a separate postgres database(Ex:- database_cust1,database_cust2 etc..) and seperate war file.

So here is the problem:-
We are facing issues with timezones as the clients are from different parts of the world. So let's say we have 2 customers american and indian, we have make sure that american is viewing/modiying according to his time zone times and indian according to IST. We have tried fixing this by setting timezone formats in postgres db using the query

**ALTER DATABASE american_db SET timezone= 'America/Los_Angeles';**

This worked fine as the data I have inserted in to the tables is being store in according to american time standards. But while retrieving the same data from java(ibatis) we are getting server time but not the time in America/Los_Angeles. I have tried searching online but none of the solutions worked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The database stores timestamptz as a timestamp in UTC and automatically converts it from and to a connection timezone. If you set the database timezone with `alter database` it will be treated as a default connection timezone for connecting clients. But some clients will quite reasonably set the connection timezone to its operating system timezone automatically, ignoring the database default.

If you want the database to convert timestamptz values automatically to and from some chosen timezone, which is different than a client's operating system timezone, then you should issue `set timezone='America/Los_Angeles'` command just after establishing connection to the database. Some programs allow to set this while configuring database credentials - I don't know what about iBATIS/MyBatis.

```
=> set timezone='America/New_York';
=> select '2018-02-17 15:17+01'::timestamptz;
 2018-02-17 09:17:00-05
=> set timezone='Asia/Kolkata';
=> select '2018-02-17 15:17+01'::timestamptz;
 2018-02-17 19:47:00+05:30
```